# Particular solution of a second order differential equation.Tom Apostol's Calculus vol.II section 6.15 exercise 14.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $L(y) = y''+ ay' + by $ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, let $f$ be the particular solution of $L(y)=0$ satisfying the conditions $f(0) = 0 $ and $f'(0) = 1$. Show that a particular solution of $L(y) = R $ is given by the formula 
$$ y_1(x) = \int_c^x f(x-t)R(t)dt        $$ 
for any choice of $c$.

**Question :** One can show this by substituting $y$ with $ y_1 $ in $L(y)$ and using Leibniz rule for integration and  $f(0) = 0 $ and $f'(0) = 1$. I am wondering if one can solve this using theorem (Tom Apostol's Calculus vol.II Theorem 6.11.)

> **THEOREM 6.11 :**  Let $u_1,.......u_n$ be $n$ independent solutions of the homogeneous $n$th order linear differential equation $L(y) = 0$ on an interval $J$. Then a particular solution $y_1$ of the non-homogeneous equation $L(y) = R$ is given by the formula 
>   $$ y_1(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k (x) v_k (x),$$
>   where $v_1,.....v_n $ are the entries of the $n \times 1$ column matrix $v$ determined by the equation 
>   $$v(x) = \int_c^x R(t)W(t)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \vdots \\0\\1\end{pmatrix} dt $$
>   where $W$ is the Wronskian matrix of $u_1,.....,u_n$ and $c$ is any point in $J$.

Combined with Abel's formula $\det W(x) = \det W(c)\exp[\int_c^x P_1(t) dt]$  $c\in J$.

My thinking is that since $f$ is a solution of $L(y)$ then $f$ has the form $f(x) = c_1e^{-ax/2}u_1(x) + c_2e^{-ax/2}u_2(x)$. Taking the Wronskian matrix  of $v_1 = e^{-ax/2}u_1(x)$ and $v_2 = e^{-ax/2}u_2(x)$ and $detW(0) = -u_1(0)e^{-ax}/c_1$ (using the fact that $f(0) = 0 $ and $f'(0) = 1$.) in Abel's formula we then have a particular solution $ y_1(x) = \sum_{k=1}^2 g_k (x) v_k (x),$ where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are the entries of the 2 x 1 column matrix given by 
$$g(x) = \int_c^x R(t)(-c_1e^{at}/u_1(0))\begin{pmatrix}-e^{-at/2}u_2(t) \\e^{-at/2}u_1(t) \end{pmatrix} dt .$$

My question is then, if we can continue from that thinking and show that $$ y_1(x) = \int_c^x f(x-t)R(t)dt        $$ is a particular solution of $L(y)=R$

Comment: Since $y_1$ is given, why don't you simply compute $L(y_1)$ ?

Comment: I was wondering if there is another way, without using Leibniz integral rule!

Comment: Leibniz rule ? there is no Leibniz rule here.

Comment: Dont we need it to calculate the derivative of the integral?because of f(x-t).

Comment: $$y'_1(x)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^x f(x-t)R(t)\,\mathrm d t=f(0)R(0)+\int_0^x f'(x-t)R(t)\,\mathrm d t$$$$=\int_0^x f'(x-t)R(t)\,\mathrm d t$$

Comment: @Surb : It should be $f(0)R(x)$ in the evaluation at $t=x$ (which of course still has the value zero).

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Indeed, thank you :-)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but is this what Leibniz integration rule states?that the derivative passes through the integral as a partial derivative of x ?Can we derive this alone from the first fundamental theorem (for one variable) and the chain rule?

Answer (score 1):

This task is related to the construction that if 
$$
L(y)=y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+...+a_1y+a_0
$$
with $a_k=const.$,
and $f$ is a solution of $L(y)=0$ with $y(0)=y'(0)=...=y^{(n-2)}(0)=0$ and $y^{(n-1)}=1$, and $\theta$ is the Heaviside unit jump function, then the product $y_1=\theta f$ solves
$$
L(\theta f)=\delta
$$
with the Dirac delta on the right side. Any other inhomogeneous problem $L(y)=R$  has then a solution $y=(\theta f)\ast R$, so that
$$
y(x)=\int_{\Bbb R}(\theta f)(x-t)R(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x-t)R(t)dt
$$
One would check what happens if the integration interval is cut at some $c$ at the lower end, presumably
$$
y_c(x)=\int_{-\infty}^cf(x-t)R(t)dt
$$
would have to be a homogeneous (or complementary) solution.